# Is it possible to change our NDIS LWF's altitude on the LWF stack?

Tags: windows-kernel, ndis

We have a possible conflict with another NDIS LWF driver, and was wondering if there is any concept similar to minifilter's altitude in NDIS LWF, so we can change our altitude to see if it resolves the issue or not.

We sometimes do the same thing with our minifilter, when there is a buggy minifilter below us that doesn't properly handle some of the requests that we generate. So I was wondering if there is anyway we can change our altitude and go above the possible problematic LWF, thus causing that driver to not receive our self made Indicated NBLs, to see if it solves the problem or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to change the order of LWFs is to change the `FilterClass`. If two LWFs have the same `FilterClass`, then their relative order is unspecified.